# There is a problem with the writing of regular expressions. If there is a problem with the following writing, how can I modify it

Tags: python

```
self.parameters[['设备机型', 'DeviceType', 'T6-800'], ['顶升抱闸', 'LiftBreak', '1'], 
['电机方向', 'MotorDir', '1']]
self.text("[10-20 10:15:44][2584][para_config_cmd][000] DeviceType:800
[10-20 10:15:44][2584][para_config_cmd][001] RobotID:613
[10-20 10:15:44][2584][para_config_cmd][002] LiftBreak:1
[10-20 10:15:45][2584][para_config_cmd][003] WiFiEnable:1
[10-20 10:15:45][2584][para_config_cmd][006] SelfCaliSpeed:300
[10-20 10:15:45][2584][para_config_cmd][007] PTTimeSecond:60
")
paralog = []

for i in range(len(self.parameters)):
    if self.parameters[i][1] in self.text:
        self.c = re.search(''+ self.parameters[i][1]+'(:.+?)[\],\n]' , self.text)
        self.paralog.append(self.c.group())
for k in range(len(self.paralog)):
self.paralog[k] = list(self.paralog[k])
```

Running results：
[['D', 'e', 'v', 'i', 'c', 'e', 'T', 'y', 'p', 'e', ':', '8', '0', '0', '\n'], ['L', 'i', 'f', 't', 'B', 'r', 'e', 'a', 'k', ':', '1', '\n']]

Want results：
[[DeviceType:800],[DeviceType:800]]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, where the code says `self.paralog[k] = list(self.paralog[k])`, what do you think this part of the code is doing? What happens if you try **not** using it? Also: please read [ask] and [mre]. It is not possible for others to run this code, because the indentation is wrong and because there is no definition for `self`. Try to distill the code to the important part, and make sure (by trying it yourself first) that someone else can **copy and paste** the code and *directly* see the *exact* problem.

Comment: What I want is to change the list nested string into a list nested list。

Comment: self.paralog[k] = list(self.par实际上我在写的时候有缩进。但是我写问题的时候忘记了。alog[k])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self` references removed, but this list comprehension returns what you're looking for.

```
import re
parameters = [['设备机型', 'DeviceType', 'T6-800'], ['顶升抱闸', 'LiftBreak', '1'], ['电机方向', 'MotorDir', '1']]
text = ("""
[10-20 10:15:44][2584][para_config_cmd][000] DeviceType:800
[10-20 10:15:44][2584][para_config_cmd][001] RobotID:613
[10-20 10:15:44][2584][para_config_cmd][002] LiftBreak:1
[10-20 10:15:45][2584][para_config_cmd][003] WiFiEnable:1
[10-20 10:15:45][2584][para_config_cmd][006] SelfCaliSpeed:300
[10-20 10:15:45][2584][para_config_cmd][007] PTTimeSecond:60
""")
 
paralog = [parameter for parameter in re.findall(r'\b([A-Za-z]\w+:\d+)',text) 
            if any(parameters_check[1] in parameter 
            for parameters_check in parameters) ]

print(paralog)
```

Output

```
['DeviceType:800', 'LiftBreak:1']
```